# MongoDb Aggregation Query, for comparing dates

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

The structure of collections is as follows

```json
[
    {
        "_id": "656996aabf58e49bcb1bc4f8",
        "sheetId": "656996aabf58e49bcb1bc4e5",
        "value": [
            {
                "value": "AMrit Anand",
                "columnId": "656996aabf58e49bcb1bc4e6",
                "detailedValue": [
                ],
                "dataType": "String",
                "isRequired": false,
                "lastEditTime": "2023-12-01T08:17:46.881Z",
                "_id": "656996aabf58e49bcb1bc4f9"
            },
            {
                "value": "OVERDUE",
                "columnId": "656996aabf58e49bcb1bc4e7",
                "detailedValue": [
                ],
                "dataType": "Status",
                "isRequired": false,
                "lastEditTime": "2023-12-01T08:17:46.881Z",
                "_id": "656996aabf58e49bcb1bc4fa"
            },
            {
                "value": "10000",
                "columnId": "656996aabf58e49bcb1bc4e8",
                "detailedValue": [
                ],
                "dataType": "Number",
                "isRequired": false,
                "lastEditTime": "2023-12-01T08:17:46.881Z",
                "_id": "656996aabf58e49bcb1bc4fb"
            },
            {
                "value": "",
                "columnId": "656996aabf58e49bcb1bc4e9",
                "detailedValue": [
                ],
                "dataType": "Number",
                "isRequired": false,
                "lastEditTime": "2023-12-01T08:17:46.881Z",
                "_id": "656996aabf58e49bcb1bc4fc"
            },
            {
                "value": "",
                "columnId": "656996aabf58e49bcb1bc4ea",
                "detailedValue": [
                    {
                        "role": 1,
                        "companyId": "1512",
                        "emailId": "hodevej733@dixiser.com",
                        "firstName": "Milind",
                        "userId": "65262d90ec1fbddbd859def2",
                        "value": "Milind"
                    },
                    {
                        "role": 2,
                        "companyId": "1512",
                        "emailId": "neetesh.kumar@rekord.in",
                        "firstName": "nitesh",
                        "userId": "652f9d464b4fdb0329b3b710",
                        "value": "nitesh"
                    }
                ],
                "dataType": "Member",
                "isRequired": false,
                "lastEditTime": "2023-12-01T08:17:46.881Z",
                "_id": "656996aabf58e49bcb1bc4fd"
            },
            {
                "value": "2023-11-28T00:00:00.000Z",
                "columnId": "656996aabf58e49bcb1bc4eb",
                "detailedValue": [
                ],
                "dataType": "Date",
                "isRequired": false,
                "lastEditTime": "2023-12-01T08:17:46.881Z",
                "_id": "656996aabf58e49bcb1bc4fe"
            },
            {
                "value": "",
                "columnId": "656996aabf58e49bcb1bc4ec",
                "detailedValue": [
                ],
                "dataType": "Label",
                "isRequired": false,
                "lastEditTime": "2023-12-01T08:17:46.881Z",
                "_id": "656996aabf58e49bcb1bc4ff"
            },
            {
                "value": "",
                "columnId": "656996aabf58e49bcb1bc4ed",
                "detailedValue": [
                ],
                "dataType": "String",
                "isRequired": false,
                "lastEditTime": "2023-12-01T08:17:46.881Z",
                "_id": "656996aabf58e49bcb1bc500"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id": "656996aabf58e49bcb1bc50a",
        "sheetId": "656996aabf58e49bcb1bc4e5",
        "value": [
            {
                "value": "AMrit Anand",
                "columnId": "656996aabf58e49bcb1bc4e6",
                "detailedValue": [
                ],
                "dataType": "String",
                "isRequired": false,
                "lastEditTime": "2023-12-01T08:17:46.881Z",
                "_id": "656996aabf58e49bcb1bc50b"
            },
            {
                "value": "OVERDUE",
                "columnId": "656996aabf58e49bcb1bc4e7",
                "detailedValue": [
                ],
                "dataType": "Status",
                "isRequired": false,
                "lastEditTime": "2023-12-01T08:17:46.881Z",
                "_id": "656996aabf58e49bcb1bc50c"
            },
            {
                "value": "5000",
                "columnId": "656996aabf58e49bcb1bc4e8",
                "detailedValue": [
                ],
                "dataType": "Number",
                "isRequired": false,
                "lastEditTime": "2023-12-01T08:17:46.881Z",
                "_id": "656996aabf58e49bcb1bc50d"
            },
            {
                "value": "",
                "columnId": "656996aabf58e49bcb1bc4e9",
                "detailedValue": [
                ],
                "dataType": "Number",
                "isRequired": false,
                "lastEditTime": "2023-12-01T08:17:46.881Z",
                "_id": "656996aabf58e49bcb1bc50e"
            },
            {
                "value": "",
                "columnId": "656996aabf58e49bcb1bc4ea",
                "detailedValue": [
                ],
                "dataType": "Member",
                "isRequired": false,
                "lastEditTime": "2023-12-01T08:17:46.881Z",
                "_id": "656996aabf58e49bcb1bc50f"
            },
            {
                "value": "2023-11-28T00:00:00.000Z",
                "columnId": "656996aabf58e49bcb1bc4eb",
                "detailedValue": [
                ],
                "dataType": "Date",
                "isRequired": false,
                "lastEditTime": "2023-12-01T08:17:46.881Z",
                "_id": "656996aabf58e49bcb1bc510"
            },
            {
                "value": "",
                "columnId": "656996aabf58e49bcb1bc4ec",
                "detailedValue": [
                ],
                "dataType": "Label",
                "isRequired": false,
                "lastEditTime": "2023-12-01T08:17:46.881Z",
                "_id": "656996aabf58e49bcb1bc511"
            },
            {
                "value": "",
                "columnId": "656996aabf58e49bcb1bc4ed",
                "detailedValue": [
                ],
                "dataType": "String",
                "isRequired": false,
                "lastEditTime": "2023-12-01T08:17:46.881Z",
                "_id": "656996aabf58e49bcb1bc512"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Need to find the documents which the conditions of `filtersConditions` array
payments made on 2023-11-28
The date provided in the `filtersConditions` array is a String.
So for valid comparison has tried converting the both the values i.e from the `filterConditions` array and the date which is stored in database as string

The query is dynamically created in JavaScript as

```js
const originalDate = new Date(filterConditions[0]);
                            originalDate.setDate(originalDate.getDate() + 1)
                            originalDate.toISOString()
                            console.log("Original Date", originalDate)
                            let gtStr = new Date(filterConditions[0]).toISOString();
                            return {
                                

                                
                                    "value": {
                                        "$elemMatch": {
                                            "columnId": columnId, "value":
                                                {
                                                    "$gte": {
                                                        "$convert": {
                                                          "input": gtStr,
                                                          "to": "date"
                                                        }
                                                      },
                                                      "$lt": {
                                                        "$convert": {
                                                          "input": originalDate,
                                                          "to": "date"
                                                        }
                                                      }
                                                }
                                        }
                                    }
                            }
```

The aggregation query implemented was

```
    db.collection.aggregate([
      {
        "$set": {
          "value": {
            "$map": {
              "input": "$value",
              "as": "item",
              "in": {
                "$mergeObjects": [
                  "$$item",
                  {
                    "value": {
                      "$switch": {
                        "branches": [
                          {
                            "case": {
                              "$eq": [
                                "$$item.dataType",
                                "Number"
                              ]
                            },
                            "then": {
                              "$cond": {
                                "if": {
                                  "$ne": [
                                    "$$item.value",
                                    ""
                                  ]
                                },
                                "then": {
                                  "$toDouble": "$$item.value"
                                },
                                "else": "$$item.value"
                              }
                            }
                          },
                          {
                            "case": {
                              "$eq": [
                                "$$item.dataType",
                                "Date"
                              ]
                            },
                            "then": {
                              "$cond": {
                                "if": {
                                  "$ne": [
                                    "$$item.value",
                                    ""
                                  ]
                                },
                                "then": {
                                  "$toDate": "$$item.value"
                                },
                                "else": "$$item.value"
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        ],
                        "default": "$$item.value"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "$match": {
          "sheetId": "656996aabf58e49bcb1bc4e5"
        }
      },
      {
        "$match": {
          "$and": [
            {
              "value": {
                "$elemMatch": {
                  "columnId": "656996aabf58e49bcb1bc4eb",
                  "value": {
                    "$gte": {
                      "$convert": {
                        "input": "2023-11-28T00:00:00.000Z",
                        "to": "date"
                      }
                    },
                    "$lt": {
                      "$convert": {
                        "input": "2023-11-29T00:00:00.000Z",
                        "to": "date"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ])
```

But the correct results are not being fetched.
The query is dynamically generated in JavaScript

Comment: Storing date/time values as string is a design flaw, you should **never** do that. Store `Date` objects. Then you can compare `Date` values with `Date` values, not string. Simply use `let gtStr = new Date(filterConditions[0])`